# Error in Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "Functions"

Tags: syntax

What do I have to change in the series?

```
//Provide proper forum data and permissions
        if(is_numeric($forum))
            $forum = self::getForumData($forum);
        $perms = is_array ($forum[10]) ? $forum[10] Functions::explodeByComma ($forum[10]);
        //Check guests
```

so that this error no longer appears?
Parse error: syntax error, unexpected identifier "Functions"